# How do I prepare data for D3 network graphs dynamically? Need web-based NodeXL

Tags: json, node.js, visualization, graph-visualization

Need help with data processing for visualization. What should I use to prepare data for network graphs that will load in a web page dynamically?

Captions from social media --> [some web version of NodeXL] --> D3 Network Visualization

I'm going to be mapping relationships between keywords from social media captions. I will need to map which keywords are most often used with others. For example, in a caption the word "gratitude" is most often used with the word "blessed", but is also used with "love".

Ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just produce the JSON to feed the visualization from the captions data?

Comment: That sounds like it could work -- I'm just not sure what algorithm to run or what JavaScript library to use in order to map the relationships between the words (most used with). Do you have any suggestions there?

Comment: You talk about "mapping relationships between keywords", from the example you make it seems like it is something like tuples. Probably something like elastic search can help you in this.

Comment: Would tuples work  if I just wanted to map how often a keyword was used with another keyword? Thank you for letting me know about Elastic Search -- that does seem like something that could work (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/graph/current/graph-introduction.html)